# .htaccess regex match all (even slashes) before last slash

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to catch everything after /project/ until the last slash, even if there's a slash in between. Is this possible?

```
/project/code-cons/isting-0f_all-ch/ars/
```

rewrite to:

```
/project/?id=code-cons/isting-0f_all-ch/ars
```

I previously used this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^project/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?pagename=project&id=$1 [L]
```

But that does not take slashes in the project id into account and so does not match the rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use this regex:

```
RewriteRule ^project/(.+?)/?$ index.php?pagename=project&id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

`(.+?)` is non-greedy regex that will capture everything until last optional regex is found.

Comment: OP may want to take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547899/which-characters-make-a-url-invalid) depending on how valid he/she would like the string to be. `.+?` literally entails *any* character.